# How to make swiftui lazyvgrid multiple columns

Tags: swiftui, lazyvgrid

I want to make a lazyvgrid with multiple columns as bellow. Large size items can be aligned with two smaller sizes.

[image]

My code is as bellow:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let paddingLeft: CGFloat = 22.0
    var body: some View {
        let widgetWidth: CGFloat = 72.0
        let widgetHeight: CGFloat = widgetWidth
        let col: Int = 4
        let widgetGap: CGFloat = floor((UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - paddingLeft * 2 - widgetWidth * CGFloat(col)) / CGFloat(col - 1))
        let widgetWidthx2: CGFloat = widgetWidth * 2 + widgetGap
        let colums1 = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: widgetWidth), spacing: widgetGap)]
        LazyVGrid(columns: colums1, spacing: widgetGap){
              ForEach(0 ..< 11){ idx in
                  RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 0.1 * Double(idx) , saturation: 1, brightness: 1))
                    .frame(width: idx == 4 ? widgetWidthx2 : widgetWidth, height: widgetHeight)
              }
          }
        .padding(.horizontal, paddingLeft)
    }
}
```

However, the result was not as expected:

[image]

Is there any way to make swiftui lazyvgrid multiple columns?

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let paddingLeft: CGFloat = 22.0
    var body: some View {
        let widgetWidth: CGFloat = 72.0
        let widgetHeight: CGFloat = widgetWidth
        let col: Int = 4
        let widgetGap: CGFloat = floor((UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - paddingLeft * 2 - widgetWidth * CGFloat(col)) / CGFloat(col - 1))
        let widgetWidthx2: CGFloat = widgetWidth * 2 + widgetGap
        let colums1 = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: widgetWidth), spacing: widgetGap, alignment: .leading)] //-- here  alignment: .leading
        LazyVGrid(columns: colums1, spacing: widgetGap){
              ForEach(0 ..< 11){ idx in
                  RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 0.1 * Double(idx) , saturation: 1, brightness: 1))
                    .frame(width: idx == 4 ? widgetWidthx2 : widgetWidth, height: widgetHeight)
                  if idx == 4 {
                      Color.clear
                  }
              }
          }
        .padding(.horizontal, paddingLeft)
    }
}
```